# How to set the icon of a dll?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dll, icons, winapi

I would like to add icon to the dll . I added the icon in resource file as IDI_ICON1               ICON                    "icon1.ico"

But still when I build the dll , I cannt see icon in the dll.

what else I need to do to show icon for dll.

I am developing dll in VC++.

Comment: you can call it `*.exe`  or `*.dll.exe`

Comment: Where do you want to see the icon?

Comment: I am not able to understand...please elaborate

Comment: I want to see the icon in explorer or when I open properties of dll, I should see the icon

Comment: No, you shouldn't.  That's not what DLLs are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to make the icon show in Windows Explorer, that's impossible.

Explorer (or rather, the shell) will only read icons from the file for EXEs and shortcuts.
All DLL files will have the standard DLL icon, no matter what you do to the DLL.

If you really want to, you can edit the registry to make the shell (on your machine only) read icons from (all) DLLs the same way it does for EXEs, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Alien: You shouldn't be trying to do this in the first place.  DLL files are internal files.

Comment: @Alien -- They are no more internal than EXE.   I'm a vendor and the product I deliver to my customers is a DLL plug-in so for me it makes sense that I should be able to customize the icon for the product I deliver.   Making it impossible seems an arbitrary decision by Microsoft.  Also in VS2019 it allows me to define an icon on the Application page for my Class Library but doesn't display it.  Why allow it to be defined if it's not to be used or displayed?