# ICON for .NET Core 3.1 Class Library DLL in Visual Studio not showing in File Explorer

Tags: c#, icons, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to define icon for a .NET Core 3.1 Class Library.  I followed the instructions on this link but ICON is not showing up on the output DLL file in File Explorer.  The ICON does show up on the Application page in Visual Studio where I defined it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-an-application-icon-visual-basic-csharp?view=vs-2019

Here is the Application window in Visual Studio.  Note that ICON is displayed following ICON file entry.

[image]

Here is what shows up in File Explorer.   The Class Library DLL file is the one highlighted in light blue.

[image]

EDIT

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550516/set-a-custom-application-icon-for-a-class-library-deployed-using-clickonce) similar question from 9 years ago.   At that time the ICON field on the Application page was grayed out.  In Visual Studio 2019 however I am able to enter an ICON file.   It just doesn't show up in File Explorer on the DLL output file.

Answer (score 1):

.dll files will only display the default icon for .dll files in Windows File Explorer. In other words, all .dll files will have the same icon, and the icon you set when compiling your code will not display like executable files will.

Comment: Additionally, this question is a duplicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268650/how-to-set-the-icon-of-a-dll

Comment: I'm a vendor and the product I deliver to my customers is a DLL plug-in so for me it makes sense that I should be able to customize the icon for the product I deliver. You've already got the file extension that tells you its a DLL.   Do they apply the same rule to obj files and other "internal" files?  Making it impossible seems an arbitrary decision by Microsoft. Also in VS2019 as shown in my original post it allows me to define an icon on the Application page for my Class Library but doesn't display it. Why allow it to be defined if it's not to be used or displayed?

Comment: also the duplicate is not an exact duplicate as it was for a C++ native DLL which is a different animal than .NET Core 3.1 Class Library I'm asking about.

Comment: The compiled language or IDE is not at issue - the problem is with the Windows operating system. .dll files do not display in Windows with custom icons. The user can set a custom icon at the system level that applies to all files of any type.

It may be that another operation system may support custom icons for .dll files, but Windows does not.

Comment: Yes I discovered VS is putting my specified ICON into the DLL file because if I rename the DLL file to .EXE then the Explorer Shell suddenly shows my ICON.  I guess it makes sense given that the binary output is not targeted only for Windows.   Sill disappointing that it's not possible to put company logo on our product.